# Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException on Basic Google Search - Newbie

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am brand new to selenium and C# and trying to implement a very simple program that goes out to Google and enters Apple Stock and searches.

When running the program, it gets to google, enters Apple Stock but is unable to hit the search button. The element doesn't appear to be blocked and I think I have the right name so I don't know why it is failing. Here is the code. Thanks

```
        //Create reference for browser
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Navigate to Google
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        //Find the element
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

        //Perform  Ops
        element.SendKeys("Apple Stock");

        //Find the element
        IWebElement element2 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK"));

        //Click on Google search
        element2.Click();
```

Comment: The Google search page is probably _the worst_ site you could have used for browser automation. Google spends a lot of effort to stop this sort of behavior (and direct you to their API). You're going to want to find a different site to use.

Comment: their terms of service are against it, but they didn't used to do much bot detection on the search page... (haven't check lately)...  you might try just sending enter key: element.SendKeys(Keys.Return);

Comment: @browsermator awesome, the enter key worked. Thanks!